# Is any eclipse special version needed to make use of getElementById etc functions in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am using Eclipse Indigo but running HTML pages in a web project. All parts of javascript are running other than getElementById, getElementsByName, innerHTML functions and also am unable to make use of events a sonSubmit etc. But other events as onBlur etc are running fine.
Also pressing ctrl + spc is not populating the above mentioned functions/events. I wish to know is any other setting needs to be done or any special Eclipse version is needed to run the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Posting a code sample would help us to help you.

Comment: Are you certain you have an element that matches the id you are trying to select by and not a class name instead? Check you spelling also. Other than that ditto on providing code.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on project (your project) from **Project Explorer**  then select **Configure** --> **Add Java Script Support** ..

Eclipse Galileo - Not sure some older versions also support